# Rails 4 with carrierwave Image uploaad fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hi when I upload my image in rails using carrier wave the paramtters of the image are passed to the controller but the image is not getting saved in the folder and there is a null record getting saved in the database.
I have added the codes for my form model and controller below.

Thanks.

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

User Controller :

class UsersController < ApplicationController

```
def new
  @contact = User.new
end

def save_user
  @contact = User.new
  @contact.first_name = params["first_name"]
  @contact.middle_name = params["middle_name"]
  @contact.photo = params["photo"]
  @contact.save
end
```

User Form:

```
<%= form_tag('#save_user',:html => {:multipart => true}) do %>
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          Name <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        </div>
        <%= text_field_tag "first_name",@contact.first_name,class:'form-control',placeholder:'First Name',:autocomplete => :off%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <%= text_field_tag "middle_name",@contact.middle_name,class:'form-control',placeholder:'Middle Name',:autocomplete => :off%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%= text_field_tag "last_name",@contact.last_name,class:'form-control',placeholder:'Last Name',:autocomplete => :off%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          DOB <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <%= text_field_tag "dob",@apprentice.dob,class:'form-control',:autocomplete => :off%>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <label> Photo </label>
      <%= file_field(:user,:photo) %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you plz share some code

Comment: I have added the links to the gist

Comment: added code in the question @Udaykumardas

Comment: Tried That its passing like this 
"photo"=>"prescription_image.jpg", but not getting saved

Comment: I am trying to save the data like @contact.first_name=params["first_name"] and @contact.save so i am using form_tag and i am passing it to custom action like save_user . and form_for needs object or model

Comment: <%= file_field_tag 'photo' %> still null in db

Comment: file_field_tag 'photo', :accept => 'image/jpeg', :multiple => true used this still not working :\

Comment: show me your log file.

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JMPj4CbyEF5L5Mz2ryfRq9ZXKa9/9RYpYcL30a/JNr5rRVRGpZ8b5pDPqpMe1pm4IdpEllBJ
fgPCz+eJK3eGtA==", "first_name"=>"", "middle_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "dob"=>"", "photo"=>"prescription_image.jpg", 
 "commit"=>"Save Details"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the multipart of the form_tag so I modified the form_tag like this to make it work

```
<%= form_tag('#save_user',:multipart => true) do %>
```